# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@codemirror/basic-setup'

Tags: reactjs, npm, codemirror

I want to use Codemirror in my React project, but when I tried to use codemirror's basicSetup as an extension, I got an error.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

import { EditorState, basicSetup } from '@codemirror/basic-setup'
import { EditorView, keymap } from '@codemirror/view'
import { defaultKeymap, indentWithTab } from '@codemirror/commands'

export const Editor = () => {
  const editor = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const startState = EditorState.create({
      doc: 'Hello World',
      extensions: [basicSetup, keymap.of([defaultKeymap, indentWithTab])],
    })

    const view = new EditorView({ state: startState, parent: editor.current })

    return () => {
      view.destroy()
    }
  }, [])

  return <div ref={editor}></div>
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXmm7.png)

I tried `npm i @codemirror/basic-setup` separately, but no progress. please help me

Comment: Are you using alias path in this project?

Comment: No, I didn't use it.